# Reading process memory of computer A on computer B?

Tags: memory-hardware, memory-access

So I was wondering if there is a way of reading process memory of one device on another. So lets say a process is running on computer A, I then use some form of connection lan, pcie etc. Once the two computers are connected. Would it be any way possible to then, say open something like cheat engine and read process memory of PC A on PC B in real time. Has something like this been done before/is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is called [RDMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_direct_memory_access) and techniques like Infiniband rely on it.